# How do I solve numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'histogram' on python

Tags: python, math

I want to randomly select numbers with the probability acording to the sum of 2 normal/gaussian distributions and make a histogram.

basicaly

```
import numpy as np    
u, vth = 0,1 # mean and standard deviation
    v= np.random.normal(u, vth, 1000)+np.random.normal(-u, vth, 1000)
    v.histogram()
```

However I get the error numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'histogram'. Another problem is that this isn't normalized so my results shouldn't be right...

Comment: ndarray has no attribute `histogram`. Use `np.histogram(v)` instead.

Comment: but that just returns the number of counts in each bin. Not the histogram itself right?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is to make a histogram plot of a normal distribution. Have you tried using matplotlib library's histogram function? It can be done easily like so:

```
import numpy as np    
u, vth = 0,1 # mean and standard deviation
v= np.random.normal(u, vth, 1000)+np.random.normal(-u, vth, 1000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(v)
```

[image: histogram]